# How to keep only specific item at Combobox

Tags: regex

I'm newbie here, and new to programing c#.

I am using `Microsoft c#`.

I want to know how to keep only specific item at `Combobox` when click on `button1`.

That item is a random word that was loaded automaticaly to the combobox1, but will contain `"-test"` word.

[image]

For example in this picture i just want to keep the list that contains `"-test"` word only in ouput combobox2 when click on button1.

To become like this

[image]

Comment: So basically you are looking for à regex to extract the words that contains `-test` ?

Comment: yes sir i want remove item that not have -test